# How to send commands to command prompt using robotframework?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to automate installer using robot framework. I am able to launch the command prompt and now the next step will be to send some commands to command prompt. Please help me with same.

I have tried a couple of ways to do this like White Library and Process Library but not able to get through.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    WhiteLibrary  
Library    SeleniumLibrary    
Library    AutoItLibrary    
Library    OperatingSystem      
Library    Process    
 *** Test Cases ***
FirstWindowsTest

  Launch Application    C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe 
  Run Process    start C:\\wyz.exe -c
```

The command prompt should get open and write commands to open another installer.

Comment: Why do you need the command prompt, instead of running each command separately?

Comment: u just want to run that command only?

Comment: @BryanOakley- i want to run this command on command prompt start C:\\wyz.exe -c

Comment: @SidaraKEO- No, there are further operations after this.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the answer, anyway it seems you should attach the cmd windows to be abble to interact with itusing presskey/Press Special Key:

```
 Launch Application    C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe
    Attach Window  ... and here i'm not able to find the rigth locator for this windows
```

I have tried:

- `Attach Window  title:"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"` => Couldn't find window with title "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
- `Attach Window  title:"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"` => Couldn't find window with title C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
- `Attach Window  title:C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe` => Couldn't find window with title "C:WINDOWSsystem32cmd.exe"
- `Attach Window  title:C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` => Couldn't find window with title C:WINDOWSsystem32cmd.exe
- `Attach Window  id:"Console Window"` => Couldn't find window with SearchCriteria AutomationId="Console Window"
- `Attach Window  id:Console Window` => Couldn't find window with SearchCriteria AutomationId=Console Window
- `Attach Window  class_name:"ConsoleWindowClass"` => Couldn't find window with SearchCriteria ClassName="ConsoleWindowClass"
- `Attach Window  class_name:ConsoleWindowClass` => Couldn't find window with SearchCriteria ClassName=ConsoleWindowClass